# Do all Android devices > 4.0 read the qemu.hw.mainkeys property?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-source

Do all Android devices > Android v4.0 always read the **qemu.hw.mainkeys** build property?
Is it built into Android itself, or is it manufacturer-specific, if a manufacturer would like to include/read this property or not?

To put it shortly: If there is a soft keyboard, will I always (on all devices) be able to disable it via **qemu.hw.mainkeys=1**?

Comment: Android devices > 4? What? API 4? Android 4.0? older than 4 years?

Comment: My mistake, how about now?

Comment: Are you trying to disable the software keyboard through an app or rooted device? Why? For testing?

Comment: I am developing a kiosk-mode app on a rooted device. I managed to get it to work on the devices I have tested so far, but I need to know that it will always work on all devices I come across.

Comment: I am not sure. Is this is a commercial app, then you could just target the devices you already know. If you are publishing to Google play, I am not sure. Maybe you get try and find all of the devices installed keyboards using an intent filter and "freeze" them with root access.

Comment: It is a commercial app that won't be released on Google Play. Which devices we run on, is unfortunately not know, it has to be able to run on any device. I don't think it's on the keyboard level. I believe it goes deeper...

Comment: If you're integrating it at that level, forget the idea of running it on any device.  Its a pipedream that won't work.  Create a set of target devices, and promise it on that with any other device being at their own risk.  Or better yet, sell them the device and software together as a solution and upcharge them for it.

Comment: Also, its been a while since I've done it so I forgot how, but I once had a bug where Swype was popping up whenever someone opened up the hardware keyboard.  So it is (or at least was) quite possible to have both at once.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Btw, It seems I can also disable soft keys by disabling package: com.android.systemui. I wonder if that is always safe though...